# How to start Qt Designer "detached" in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

In previous version of Qt Tools for Visual Studio, when opening an .ui file, Visual Designer started normally, in it's own main window. Now it starts as a docked window inside the Visual Studio IDE, and I have to press the "Detach" link every time. Is there any setting to start Qt Designer "detached" by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set **Run in detached window** to **True** in extension options:
[image]